# Create an object and print it out but turns out printing the reference. How to solve this?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

Hi I was looking at another post on stackoverflow about objects, instances.

I tried out some code.

```
public class Puppy{

   public Puppy(String name){
      // This constructor has one parameter, name.
     System.out.println(name);
   }

   public static void main(String []args){
      // Following statement would create an object myPuppy
      Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("Tommy");
      Puppy myPuppy2 = new Puppy ("Sally");
      System.out.println(myPuppy);
   }
 }
```

The output is

```
Tommy
Sally
Puppy@58886ad0
```

Question: 
when I try to print out the object myPuppy in the main method, it prints out its reference instead of the value? How should I solve this?

Also, some mentioned that I did not actually store the puppy's name and I need to write a override toString method to print out the value instead of the reference.
How should I accomplish the above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Override `toString` in `Puppy`. Also, you aren't storing the `name` in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `toString()` on `Puppy`...

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Puppy[name=" + name + "]"; 
}
```

Obviously, make the `String` it returns suit your needs.

**Edit**: And as others have mentioned, make sure you actually *store* the name when constructing a `Puppy`.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! how should I store the name (or the variable?) while constructing a Puppy object?

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure you're referencing the specific variable within the Puppy so in order to best do this you'll need to make a "name" variable in the puppy class and then System.out.println(myPuppy.name); or somethign to that effect, because as it is you're not actually storing the puppy's name

Comment: Thanks a lot! How should I store the value of the puppy's name?

Comment: Alright so 1) separate your main class and the puppy class, then within the puppy class create a String name, in the constructor for puppy make it take a String and make name = to the received string, then from the main class(where you instantiate a Puppy object parsing in a String value) call System.out.println(MyPuppy.name)

Answer (score 0):

With that last `System.out.println` you enter a object as parameter. What you get back (`Puppy@58886ad0`) is a object reference.

To get value you have to override the `toString`
Resulting in:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Puppy's name: " + name; 
}
```

Every object as a toString methode, but this will most of time give a refernce back, by overwriting it java will use your version of `toString()`.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot! Yeah I tried using System.out.println(myPuppy.toString()); but it still gives me the reference.  Then I tried your method but it completely gives me a compiler error. Then I tried public String toString(Puppy name) {
    return "Puppy's name: " + name; 
   } and then System.out.println(myPuppy.toString()) in the main method. but still gives me the reference

Comment: @huskylove first you need to store the name in a variable -> private String name ; In your constructor you can set the name -> this.name =name; after you have done this. you can copy paste toString code. In your main you can call it by->System.out.println(myPuppy.toString());